# when I call more than one provider in didChangeDependencies in flutter ,it shows me error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

When I call more than one provider in  didChangeDependencies .It shows me this error" A Products was used after being disposed,Once you have called dispose() on a Products, it can no longer be used."

It's my providers in main.dart.

```
MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => Auth(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
            create: (_) => Products(null),
            update: (ctx, auth, previousproduct) => Products(auth.userid)
//              previousproduct == null ? [] : previousproduct.items),
            ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, AddressData>(
//          create: (context) => AddressData(null,[]),
          update: (Context, auth, previousAddresses) => AddressData(auth.userid,
              previousAddresses == null ? [] : previousAddresses.Addresses),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Orders>(
//          create: (context) => Orders(null, []),
          update: (ctx, auth, previousorders) => Orders(
              auth.userid, previousorders == null ? [] : previousorders.orders),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => Cart(),
        ),
      ],
```

It's my didchangedependencies in homescreen.dart.

```
void didChangeDependencies() {
    final prod = Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false);
      // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
      prod.fetchandsetproduct();
      prod.fetchcategoriesproduct();
      final prod2 = Provider.of<Auth>(context,listen: false);
      prod2.getcurrentuser();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: I/flutter (25688): A Products was used after being disposed.
I/flutter (25688): Once you have called dispose() on a Products, it can no longer be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can call any number of provider

AboutusBlock aboutusBlock;
Loader loader;
HomeBlock homeBlock;
InitialBlock initialBlock;


@override 
void didChangeDependencies() {
super.didChangeDependencies();
final aboutusBlock = Provider.of<AboutusBlock>(context);
final loader = Provider.of<Loader>(context);
final homeBlock = Provider.of<HomeBlock>(context);
final initialBlock = Provider.of<InitialBlock>(context);
if (this.aboutusBlock != aboutusBlock ||
    this.loader != loader ||
    this.homeBlock != homeBlock ||
    this.initialBlock != initialBlock) {
  this.loader = loader;
  this.aboutusBlock = aboutusBlock;
  this.homeBlock = homeBlock;
  this.initialBlock = initialBlock;
  Future.microtask((){
    homeBlock.getHomeConfig(loader, initialBlock);
    aboutusBlock.getAboutUsConfig(loader);});
}
}
```

Comment: It's not working sir, error remaining same .when I call Auth and Products provider call in didchangedependencies ,Products provider automatically dispose.

Comment: I am using with same way its working fine use same way.show me your code.

Comment: loader.getcurrentuser() and aboutusBlock.fetchcategoriesproduct  are working but aboutusBlock.fetchandsetproduct() is not working.